# Google App Engine flexible price

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, price

Rails application currently running on App Engine Flexible,
It is close to $15 from March 1st to March 10th, I feel that the infrastructure cost is somewhat higher.

I set it so that access to the application rarely occurs and the resource of app.yml is minimized.
Do you have anything to keep in mind?
Or is the price of App Engine Flex like this?

It is the setting value confirmed by the GCP console.

```
runtime: ruby
api_version: '1.0'
env: flexible
threadsafe: true
env_variables:
  RAILS_MASTER_KEY: dd89c19c2ee45246d68b8b3765625ce7
automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
  max_num_instances: 2
  cpu_utilization:
    target_utilization: 0.5
resources:
  memory_gb: 0.6
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing#flexible-environment-instances. You have 1 core and .6+.4 = 1GB ram, so yes, you're around the minimum price for your config.

Comment: Thank you very much.
I did not know that this setting will be ...
".6 + .4 = 1 GB"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Google Cloud Platform Pricing Calculator](http://Google%20Cloud%20Platform%20Pricing%20Calculator) for that or calculate it yourself using the prices in [App Engine Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing#flexible-environment-instances):

- vCPU  per core hour   $0.0526
- Memory    per GB hour $0.0071

So in your case:

- 1 vCPU * 0.0526 $ per vCPU = 0.0526 $ per hour
- (0.6 GB + 0.4 GB) * 0.0071 $ per GB = 0.00426 $ per hour

Then 0.05686$ per hour for 240 hours is 13.6464$ for one instance over 10 days, which is close to what you paid.

Comment: Thanks!
I understood the content.